# Add Image to an Apple Watch Button

Tags: ios, xcode, image, apple-watch

I want to do is add an image to one of my buttons. I uploaded an image to my Assets folder and whenever I add it as a background it comes out blank. I even tried adding a group with a background and it still doesn't work. I don't know why its not working. When I set a color to the button it shows but a background image won't show up. It seems so simple but when I run it the background is black. Please help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: is the name of your image actually "bluegradient2x" or is the name actually "bluegradient"? Also, make sure that your image is added to your WatchKit assets folder and not your App's Asset folder (they are different)

Comment: That is the actual name and it lets me select it but it just doesn't show up when I run it. The images are in my Assets WatchKit Extension folder.

Comment: Set a breakpoint after it loads and see if the background image property of the button is nil.  If so then that would help figure out if the issue is with how you set the button image, the image itself, or some other issue. Also, try setting the image on an image view on the same screen to see if the image will show up there.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to get it to work, I deleted the images and renamed them and put them in the WatchKit App instead go the WatchKit Extension.

Answer (score 0):

The Images worked after I moved the images to the Assets folder of the WatchKit App instead of the WatchKit App Extension. Also, I changed the names to make sure they were correct.

Comment: Probably it would have worked if you added the image's extension (i.e. `.png`) to the image name in storyboard.

Comment: You should include image assets that you use in your Interface Builder in the WatchKit App's Assets catalog and include the ones you use in code in your WatchKit Extension's Assets catalog.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, first time I try new a Image set, set it's name, and then drag the image file in. But doesn't work.

Then some example video came into my mind and I directly drag the image file into Assets.xcassets, then set the file to Apple Watch only, and then drag the file to 2x. And everything is OK.

Looks like a bug somehow, but anyway it works. 
[image]